# Translation missing activeadmin, Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I translated my active admin menu :

```
# encoding: utf-8
ActiveAdmin.register City do
    menu :parent => "Données géographiques", :label => I18n.t(:cities)
end
```

In my active_admin.fr.yml :

```
    fr:
      active_admin:
        dashboard: "Tableau de Bord"
        dashboard_welcome:
          welcome: "Bienvenue dans Active Admin. Ceci est la page par défaut."
          call_to_action: "Pour ajouter des sections au tableau de bord, consultez 'app/admin/dashboards.rb'"
      cities: "Villes"
```

In my local (debian 6) everything works fine, but on my pre-production (debian 6), it's writter :

```
translation missing: fr.cities
```

I tried to reboot apache, clear cache, reload I18n... I failed.

Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution, you have to write that on your application.rb :

```
config.before_configuration do
  I18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
  I18n.locale = :fr
  I18n.default_locale = :fr
  config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
  config.i18n.locale = :fr
  # bypasses rails bug with i18n in production\
  I18n.reload!
  config.i18n.reload!
end

config.i18n.locale = :fr
config.i18n.default_locale = :fr
```

Reboot apache and that's good!

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution, I just ran into the same problem!

Comment: The first three line was enough for me.

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me:

```
config.after_initialize do
  I18n.reload!
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution, add this in application.rb

```
config.before_configuration do # FIX conflict I18n ActiveAdmin
  I18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
  I18n.locale = I18n.default_locale = config.i18n.default_locale
  I18n.reload!
end
```